# how to test a script that checks window is undefined with jest?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, mocking

with an imported class, i would normally just do `jest.mock('foo.js')` and add my implementation... but it doesn't work with the window object. even though i can properly mock it in my test, when i run the script, window is not mocked. i still want to be able to run this test in a browser env, so how would i mock the window object in my script environment vs the test environment?

below is contrived code of the current approach i have been working with...

foo.js

```js
export default class Foo {
  validate() {
    if (window === undefined) {
      throw new Error('must be run in a browser')
    }
  }
}
```

foo.test.js

```js
import Foo from 'foo.js'

it('should throw an error if not in a browser', () => {
  const foo = new Foo()
  const validateError = () => {
    foo.validate()
  }

  let windowSpy = jest.spyOn(global, 'window', 'get')
  windowSpy.mockImplementation(() => undefined)

  // this passes
  expect(window).toBeUndefined()

  // this fails
  expect(validateError).toThrow()
})
```

Comment: Can you provide a way to reproduce the problem? It should work the way you did it, and it does, https://repl.it/repls/WigglyBlueGenerics . Double check you didn't mock the module. This includes `__mocks__`. Also, `window === undefined` check is mostly pointless because normally it will throw an error when you try to access nonexistent global.

Comment: first thing... really liking repl.it!... i was able to play around with it enough, to finally troubleshoot my issue(s)... one was a bonehead mistake with not wrapping my single-line function when i wasn't using `return` explicitly, but then the big problem, was other tests polluting other tests from not tearing down. i feel so much better knowing that what makes sense in my head, does actually work... and i wouldn't have found my problems nearly as fast without your help today, and the link to repl. tyvm!

Answer (score 1):

You can give `delete global.window` a try (only tested on repl.it)

```
const Foo = require('./Foo');

describe('Foo', () => {
  const foo = new Foo()

  describe('if there is NO global window', () => {
    beforeAll(() => {
      delete global.window
    })

    it('should throw an error', () => {
      expect(() => foo.validate()).toThrow()
    })
  })

  describe('if there IS a global window', () => {
    beforeAll(() => {
      global.window = {}
    })
    it('should not throw an error', () => {
      expect(() => foo.validate()).not.toThrow()
    })
  })
})
```

[working example](https://repl.it/repls/WelcomeMediumpurpleComments#Foo.test.js)